# How to get MaskedTextBox to left pad a number with zeroes?

Tags: wpf, maskedtextbox

Using the WPF Toolkit MaskedTextBox in an MVVM app.  I have it's value property bound to a property that is an Int32 valuetype.

The Mask is "00000000".  But all it shows is my raw number, 149, instead of, 00000149

Shouldn't it be left padding with 0s ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Mask" in your case just means "accept eight digits", it doesn't do anything else. You can read more here: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MaskedTextBox

(Supported Mask Strings section)

For the solution, you should either:

- Use StringFormat in your binding, try this: **StringFormat={}{0:00000000}**
- Writing a [ValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) to support what you actually need (although this is not it's purpose).

More on [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I've decided to make a custom control that inherits from textbox to deal with these special "digits" fields.